# trigram frequency in dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have two lists:

```
    list1 = ["T" "UH", "T"]
    list2 = ["t", "oo", "t"]
```

The first list is phonemes, and the second list is graphemes, each corresponding with one another. I want to be able to create a tuple(phoneme, grapheme) as a 2-tuple key of a default dictionary, and the grapheme sequences as ints.

I want it to print out like this:

```
    defaultdict(, {('T', 'oo'): {'t': 1}, ('UH', 't'): {'oo': 1}, ('T', '^'): {'t': 1}}))
```

Where the "^" value indicates that this is the first grapheme that starts the word.

So far I have this:

```
    from collections import defaultdict

    d = defaultdict(dict)

    list1 = ["T" "UH", "T"]
    list2 = ["t", "oo", "t"]

    for char in list1:
       d[char] += 1
```

Comment: Where do the 1's in your example come from? It appears the general form of the `defaultdict` is `(current phoneme, preceding grapheme): {current grapheme: 1}`. Why the 1?

Comment: Yeah that's just the count of each grapheme in list2. That's just how the trigram frequency works. It gets the  frequency of a given grapheme sequence being associated with a given phoneme, and then follows a particular grapheme sequence.

Comment: @James Buerger Did I make sense?

Comment: Yeah, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will do the trick.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

phonemes = ["T", "UH", "T"]
graphemes = ["t", "oo", "t"]
# Create offset list for dict key
graphemes_offset = ['^'] + graphemes[:len(graphemes)-1]

for ph, g, g_o in zip(phonemes, graphemes, graphemes_offset):
  d[(ph,g_o)][g] = d[(ph, g_o)].setdefault(g,0) + 1
```

I renamed the variables to distinguish between the lists and created a third, offset list to keep the for loop simple.

Comment: Thank you very much @James Buerger
Is there a way where I where I can print this out like this:                                 
defaultdict(, {('T', 'oo'): {'t': 1}, ('UH', 't'): {'oo': 1}, ('T', '^'): {'t': 1}}))
where there is no "class dict".

Comment: I'm trying to combine it with another dictionary, wherby "class dict" only gets shown at the front.
like this:
(defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'T': {'t': 2}, 'UH': {'oo': 1}}), defaultdict(, {('T', 'oo'): {'t': 1}, ('UH', 't'): {'oo': 1}, ('T', '^'): {'t': 1}}))

The first half is my defaultdict(dict) I created earlier

Comment: It will always have 'class dict' when you print it. By combine it, you can have all items in a single `defaultdict` by using `update`: if `d1` and `d2` are dictionaries, `d1.update(d2)` will combine them into one.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully the following code will nudge you towards the solution you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

phonemes = ["T", "UH", "T"]
graphemes = ["t", "oo", "t"]

for char in range(len(phonemes)):
    if (char != (len(phonemes) - 1)):
        d[(phonemes[char],graphemes[char + 1])]
    else:
        d[(phonemes[char],'^')]

for currentPhenome in d:
    d[currentPhenome] = {graphemes[phonemes.index(currentPhenome[0])]:1}

print(d)
```

Output is:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {('T', '^'): {'t': 1}, ('T', 'oo'): {'t': 1}, ('UH', 't'): {'oo': 1}})
```